# How to get chance of one ball gonna fall to red zone if $3$ balls of $5$ fall into red zone have $1%$

Tags: probability

Throw $5$ balls, they can fall on a red or blue field.
The chance that $3$ balls out of $5$ fall on the red field = $1\%$.
Calculate what chance of the one ball gets into the red field, so that this condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Are the probabilities, that a given ball will fall to the red zone, independent? If they are, I would use the binomial theorem ...

Comment: Yes, they are independent. So 5 balls are throwed one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @stochastic's answer, you want to solve
$$10 \,p^3 (1-p)^2 =\epsilon$$

Consider that the rhs is the Taylor series to $O(p^6)$ and use series reversion. You would get
$$p=\frac{\epsilon ^{1/3}}{\sqrt[3]{10}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \epsilon ^{2/3}}{3\
   5^{2/3}}+\frac{\epsilon }{10}+O\left(\epsilon ^{4/3}\right)$$ Using $\epsilon=10^{-2}$ you have
$$p=\frac{323}{3000}=0.107667$$ while the exact solution is $0.107910$.

Comment: Nice! I if you want to get the other answer, you can repeat this process this time with $u = 1-p$ as you small variable. Basically, the first equation becomes $10 (1-u)^3 u^2 = \epsilon$. The inversion becomes $1-p = u =\frac{3 \epsilon}{20}+\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{10}}+\dots$, which gives $p \approx 0.96688$ compared to the direct solution $p\approx 0.9667$.

Comment: @stochastic. Thanks. I did not to do it, letting it ot the OP. It is quite tricky to consider that a polynomial of degree $n$ is a Taylor expansion to $O(x^{n+1})$ but very useful for many applications when the variable is small. Cheers :-)

Comment: Cool, +1 for teaching me a new technique!

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a probability $p$ of each ball landing in red and probability $1-p$ of landing in blue. I will assume all trials are independent. Then the chance of $3$ out $5$ landing in red is
$$
{5\choose 3} p^3 (1-p)^2 = 0.01 \implies p^3(1-p)^2 = 0.001
$$
This is a fifth-order polynomial equation, and I believe there is no analytic solution for this equation, but numerically, there are two solutions for $0<p<1$: $p\approx 0.108$ and $p \approx 0.967$.

Comment: I got $0.001$ by dividing $1\%$ by ${5\choose 3} = 10$.