# How to get chance of one ball gonna gets in the red zone if 3 balls of 5 fall into red zone have 48% chance

Tags: probability

Throw 5 balls, they can fall on a red or blue field. The chance that 3 balls out of 5 fall on the red field = 48%. Calculate what chance of the one ball gets into the red field, so that this condition is fulfilled.

Well, I got answer about 1%, but for 48% it stop works.
[How to get chance of one ball gonna fall to red zone if $3$ balls of $5$ fall into red zone have $1%$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693831/how-to-get-chance-of-one-ball-gonna-fall-to-red-zone-if-3-balls-of-5-fall-in#3693844)

Comment: Do not [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695769/321264). Edit your old post to share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: There is no solution for 
$$
{5 \choose 3} p^3 (1-p)^2 = 0.48
$$
Actually, the highest value that the expression can have, is approximately $0.3456$. You can verify this from the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/62nf8tizp4

Comment: @MattiP. *Exactly* $0.3456$ as it is $10 \left(\frac35\right)^3\left(\frac25\right)^2$